# Automatically run certain scripts at first login/PC startup

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have some scripts that I would like to run when OS starts up(e.g. script that connects to internet). Right now I'm doing it by running it every time I log in after PC startup. How can I make it so that the script will run automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in two different ways:

- First way is to modify your **/etc/rc.local** which run once at the startup:

  1. make your script excutable : `chmod +x path_to_script/script_file`
  2. add the script **absolute path** to your */etc/rc.local* before the `exit 0`
- Second way:

  1. put your script under **/etc/init.d**: `mv path_to_script/script_file /etc/init.d/`
  2. make it executable: `chmod +x /etc/init.d/script_to_run`
  3. create symbolic link to your script under **/etc/rc.d/**:    `ln -s /etc/init.d/script_to_run /etc/rc.d/`

Comment: Is there a difference?

Comment: @MatthewRock generally you can use __rc.local__ for scripts to be run only once at boot such as a kind of configuration or any thing else without having to deal with the **stop|start** service stuff, but when you want to have script that work as a service and to be able to stop and restart it any time after the boot it's better put it under __/etc/init.d__